# Use Android camera to read non-HTTP QR codes to send intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code

I'm trying to use a QR code, read in the native camera app, to launch our app with a parameter.

I had expected that I could use a custom scheme, with a URL like
myApp://parameter.
But QR codes of that form don't cause the camera app (I'm testing on a Pixel, if that makes a difference) to pop up the button offering to open the URL.

I can only get that to happen if I use an http://myapp.com/parameter URL, and that causes the camera to offer both our app and the browser as possible launches. That's not what I want.

I'm aware that App Links is the newer and shiner way to do this, but that requires a network connection which is not always available in our use case.

So, what I would like to know is what URL schemes the built-in camera supports, in the hope that there is one that I can use to launch our app and not the browser. Or, is there any other way to build a URL that will launch an intent but not the browser ?